# Does your company name effect SEO and ranking?

Tags: seo

This is a slightly odd question so bear with me...

I work at a business where the word 'Free' is part of the company name (which is a made up word - actually the first 4 letters of the company name spells 'free'). The URL is the *companyname.com*

It just so happens that we can't seem to help but mention the company name within our content to the point where it can appear on a page up to 30+ times.

It also happens that our main angle is that we try to entice people to buy products and services from us with the offer of getting various extras free of charge when they sign up and purchase products and services.

So on any given page on our website (and there are a ton of pages (hundreds)) you may come across the word 'free' (either on its own, or as part of our company name) up to 70+ times.

I can only imagine this is going to look very, very odd to Google and other search engines and they will rank us accordingly. That would be my understanding regardless of the word in question but when you couple the huge amount of repetition of one word, plus the fact that the one word happens to set off warning bells in search engines, email clients, people's brains and more - are we causing ourselves a lot of ranking / search engine headaches down to:

1. The company name / url happens to contain the word 'free'.
2. We repeat the company name over and over on our webpages.
3. Our main (possibly only) selling point are the freebies and extras when you purchase products from us so as a result, the word 'free' crops up an awful lot on our pages.

Many thanks.

Comment: In fact if the domain contains "free", it will be less dangerous for you to use it.